# OGG file length fixing program (to turn OGG files with 1:45 audio length to correct length)

Tags: audio, debugging, audio-editing, repair

I have an OGG song file that I want to play with StepMania dance program on my computer but it is one of those songs that were patched so that it could be played on any of the In The Groove Arcade machines and sadly, I couldn't play the song in StepMania when I'm editing the notes. So I feel the only way out is to modify the OGG file so that the song length is the original song length, not 1 minute and 45 seconds.

Doing searches on the net led me to a utility called itgoggpatch but when I attempted to access the resource, Google could not locate it. The resource is:  https://code.google.com/archive/p/itgoggpatch

Now I don't have to specifically need that particular program, I just need any compiled program for Linux or for an old windows version or even for DOS that will take an ogg file as input and store the original length of the song back into the file (not the 1 minute and 45 second length).

Any pointers to the best program I should use and where a download is available?

Comment: I've just opened and downloaded both files just fine?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the resources are still available on Google Code, but Google Code is in Archive mode.

It seems that the creator of this patch move it to Github under https://github.com/LHCGreg/itgoggpatch and you may download the releases from here 
https://github.com/LHCGreg/itgoggpatch/releases